# Trusted Location still showing security warning for compiled Access DB path

Tags: windows-registry, office365, microsoft-access, security-warning

[Asked on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72426295/2419128) but Super User was suggested

Been puzzling over this for a few days.
I install a compiled Access 2016 database (accde) into a `%localappdata%` program subfolder and add that folder to an Access Trusted Location. Kind of following [@Gustav's post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31513908/2419128) to use that folder.

Yet it continually starts up with the security warning even on my computer - listing same folder that is my trusted location.

Is it possible there is a Group Policy that overrides this setting? I am on a developer laptop that builds the app to be installed on to the same corporate environment. Users all see [this message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sk4CY.png).

Or am I missing exceptions to the rule?

I have tried manually setting the Trust Location in Access, editing the registry and setting the registry key via Inno Setup installer. All set the key correctly, but make no difference to the startup security warning message.

**MS-Access Trusted Location setup**

[image: Trusted Location]

**What it looks from Explorer**

[image: Folder Location in Explorer]

**Registry Setting**

[image: Registry Setting]

Starting up this ACCDE file results in

**this security message**:

[image: Security Message]

Comment: "Is it possible there is a Group Policy that overrides this setting?"- Have you asked your Administrator? Can you show the properties of the file?

Comment: You have created a trusted location, for your user, each user would have to do that same.  Have you tried some other location as a test?

Comment: Installer creates the location for each user. I'm just testing on my own PC now. They get same messages. Yes I can show file properties. Admin hasn't knowingly added a policy for this - and I can't see anything in registry for Local Machine